# SESSIONS vars not preserved on jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i have a big problem burning my head on my website. Ive been working a login system based on this public project https://github.com/panique/php-login-minimal . I made some adaptations, but the main code is basically the same. This is my main.php code, where all the website is based on:

```
<?php


 // include the configs / constants for the database connection
  require_once("config/db.php");

 // load the login class
   require_once("classes/Login.php");

// create a login object. when this object is created, it will do all login/logout stuff automatically
// so this single line handles the entire login process. in consequence, you can simply ...

 $login = new Login();

if(! session_id() ) {
 echo "No session! Starting, now."; session_start(); 
} 
else
{
    echo session_id();
}
?>

 <html> 
    <head> 
    <title>Main</title> 
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0;" />
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />


        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />


        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.css" />

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.js"></script>


        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/noty/packaged/jquery.noty.packaged.min.js"></script>



            <script src="libraries/RGraph.common.core.js" ></script>
            <script src="libraries/RGraph.bar.js" ></script>



        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
            <script src="js/login.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /></head>
<body> 
<div data-role="page" class="page contact-form">
        <div data-role="header">
            <a href="login.php" data-icon="arrow-l" data-direction="reverse">Voltar</a>
            <a href="index.php" data-icon="home" data-direction="reverse">Home</a>
            <h1>Login</h1>
        </div><!--/header-->
        <div color-bar>
            <div data-role="content" align="center" id="logina">
                <!--<h3><em>Faca o login</em></h3>
                    <p>Aqui, voce acessara sua pagina exclusiva.</p>-->
                    <a href="#"><img src='img/logo2.png' alt="portfolio image" /></a>
                    <hr />
                    <div id="contact-form-wrapper">
                    <div data-role="content">
                        <?php

                    echo $_SESSION['user_login_status'];


                        if ($login->isUserLoggedIn() == true) {


                            if (isset($_GET["planilha"])){
                                include("views/planilha.php");
                                die();
                            }
                            if (isset($_GET["fichas"])){
                                include("views/fichas.php");
                                die();
                            }
                            if (isset($_GET["progresso"])){
                                include("progresso.php");
                                die();
                            }
                            if (isset($_GET["setexe"])){
                                include("views/setexe.php");
                                die();
                            }
                            if (isset($_GET["addficha"])){
                                include("views/addficha.php");
                                die();
                            }
                            if (isset($_GET["editficha"])){
                                include("views/editficha.php");
                                die();
                            }
                            if (isset($_GET["addficha2"])){
                                include("views/addficha2.php");
                                die();
                            }
                            include("views/logged_in.php");

                        }






                        else {
                            session_start();

                                include("views/loginsub.php");
                        }

                        ?>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div id="contact-form-success"></div>

                <div class="social-icons">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="img/social_icons/facebook-logo-square.png" alt="facebook" /></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="img/social_icons/twitter-logo-square.png" alt="twitter" /></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="img/social_icons/linkedin-logo-square2.png" alt="linkedin" /></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div><!--/social-icons-->
        </div><!-- /content -->
    </div><!-- /page -->



</body>
```

This code works fine if jQuery Mobile is disabled. But if i enable it, the SESSIONS vars set by the Login class lost when i change the page. The session_id is still preserved, only the Variables are gone. ive already added a session_start() on every page included in this main file. Ive already changed the login submission to ajax, and its still not working. I also tried to disable cache, and no answer. Its really something with the variables. Anyone can help me?

Thanks

Comment: You need `session_start()` once at that top of that file, not every included file

Comment: ive already tried that, not working. Thanks for the answer